# Shell-Script Bash

Tags: shell-script, awk, gawk

I have this loop in the shell script, but it seems I don't fully understand what it does:

especially gawk -v

```
for ((k=$1; $k<3 + 3 ; k=$k + $3))
do
echo $k | gawk -v s=4 '{print $1*s}'
done
```

Assume the arguments we have are 2 10 4

Comment: I'd be happy to answer none school work questions. Could you elaborate on in what context this is used and how it fits into a larger picture? You specify three arguments - but only $1 and $3 is used..

Comment: @ClausAndersen gawk -v means that we are assigning the valuse of s to 4 but how about the `{print $1*s}`

Comment: This is not a question, just a statement.

Comment: What shell is it for?

Comment: No assign 4 to s.

Comment: `$1` is field one. Print used to mean print to the teletypes, but then we replaced the teletypes with visual-display-units, then replaced the whole lot with virtual terminals. print just sends output to stdout, that (as it is not re-directed) will go to your terminal window.

Comment: Did you run the script and see what it does?

Comment: I just did not want to do your homework. Others did - so good for you. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

I can only imagine this is a homework question.

Let's break this down.  Firstly you have a loop which starts at `$1` and increments by `$3` and will stop at `6`.  So if you pass in `2 10 4`, then the loop will start at `2`,  and increment by `4`.  It will immediately stop because `2 + 4 = 6`.

So the following just print's `2`.  With the arguments `2 10 4`.

```
for ((k=$1; $k<3 + 3 ; k=$k + $3))
do
    echo $k
done
```

---

Each time round the loop, you process the output using `gawk -v s=4 '{print $1*s}'`.  This is a very small "awk" program.  It sets a variable `s=4`.  Then prints `$1*s` (ie: it calculates `2 * 4` and just prints `8`.

Answer (score 1):

The `awk` bit just prints the current value of `$k` (this is `$1` in the `awk` code as it is read from the input) times 4 (this is the value of the `awk` variable `s`, as set on the command line).

It would be shorter to do

```
printf '%d\n' "$(( 4*k ))"
```

The loop goes from whatever the first argument is to 5 in steps of the third argument.  The second argument does not make any difference.

Therefore, the whole thing could be simplified down to

```
seq "$(( 4*$1 ))" "$(( 4*$3 ))" 20
```

The three arguments to GNU `seq` are "*start*, *increment*, and *end*". This is for the *output*, and the output will always be four times the current value of the loop variable.  The loop starts at `$1`, so the output starts at four times that. The loop increments by `$3`, so we increment by four times that.  The loop ends with `$k` at a maximum of 5 (one less than `3+3`), so the output ends at `4*5`.

Or, if you want to do that `seq` call as a `bash` loop instead:

```
for (( k = 4*$1; k <= 20; k += 4*$3 )); do
    printf '%d\n' "$k"
done
```

And, as you see,

```
for (( k = $1; k <= 5; k += $3 )); do
    printf '%d\n' "$(( 4*k ))"
done
```

is not far from that.